# How are bootstrap methods registered to the constant pool in Java?

Tags: java, invokedynamic

I've been poking around *invokedynamic* and *MethodHandles* information recently.

It seems that BOTH `Linkage.registerBootstrapMethod()` and `@BootstrapMethod` are deprecated as means of marking bootstrap methods as such.

**How are they registered to the constant pool?**

Answer (score 3):

As of Java 8, there is no Java language-level support for registering bootstrap methods.  Bootstrap methods are registered by a bytecode emitter (source-to-bytecode compiler, bytecode transformer, instrumentation agent, etc.) in the [BootstrapMethods attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.23) in the class file(s) from which they are used by [CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic_info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.10) values in the constant pool, which are in turn referenced by invokedynamic instructions.